# jQuery селекторы, выбрать всё кроме

Tags: jquery

Делаю шапку сайта, где есть выплывающее меню регистрации, в котором в свою очередь тоже выплывающие фрагменты имеются. Для правильной работы *jQuery* кода (чтобы выглядело так как мне нужно) мне надо обобрать все элементы, кроме одного. Хочу сделать блок `div`, выплывающий при клике на кнопку и скрывающийся при клике на любое место за ним.

Вот код *jQuery*:

```
//Выплывает рамка для ввода контактной информации) 

var i = true;

var j = false;


$('#contaks').click(function(){
  j = true;
  // alert(j);
});
$('#registrationForm:not(#contaks + div)').click(function(){ //СЮДА НУЖНО ОТОБРАТЬ ВСЁ, КРОМЕ #contaksFormSlide!!!!! И КРОМЕ ПОЛЕЙ e-mail и номер Телефона которые находятся в данном блоке div

  if(j){
    $('#contaksFormSlide').slideToggle(500, function(){
      if(i){
        $("#contaks").html('Контактная информация<img id="downArrow" src="images/arrowUp.png" class="arrowStyle "/>');
        i = !i;
      }
      else{
        $("#contaks").removeClass('ALERT').addClass('forContaks').html('Контактная информация<img id="downArrow" src="images/arrowDown.png" class="arrowStyle "/>');
        i = !i;
        j = false;
      }
    });
  }

});
```

Вот код Html:

```
<div id="registrationForm">
  <form>
    <span id="FIO">
      <input id="name" type="text" value="Имя" class="forFIO"/>
      <input id="surname" type="text" value="Фамилия" class="forFIO"/>
      <input id="patronymic" type="text" value="Отчество" class="forFIO"/><br />
    </span>
    <span id="userData">
      <span id="personalInfo">

        <button id="contaks" type="button" class="forContaks">Контактная информация<img id="downArrow" src="images/arrowDown.png" class="arrowStyle "/></button>
        <div id="contaksFormSlide">
          <input type="text" value="e-male"/><br />
          <input type="text" value="Номер Вашего телефона" />
        </div>

      </span>
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Пробовал

```
#registrationForm:not(#contaks + div)
#registrationForm:not(#contaksFormSlide)
```

И кучу других методов, не фильтруется.
Версия *jQuery 2.0.2*

Comment: Так можно включить в результат все элементы, попадающий под `selector1` и из этой выборки исключить все, попадающие под `selector2`:  

    $( 'selector1' ).not( 'selector2' ).click( ... );

Comment: Спасибо, однако не получается( блок div '#contaksFormSlide' все равно реагирует на клик. У меня в нем, как видно из кода, часть формы расположена, но заполнить её у пользователя не получится, так как он скрывается при клике в графу заполнения или же при клике на div он скрывается...)

Comment: Есть ещё варианты?

Comment: Попробовал так:

$('#registrationForm').not('#contaksFormSlide').click(function(){
  
  if(j){
   $('#contaksFormSlide').slideToggle(500, function(){
    if(i){
     $("#contaks").html('Контактная информация<img id="downArrow" src="images/arrowUp.png" class="arrowStyle "/>');
     i = !i;
    }
    else{
     $("#contaks").removeClass('ALERT').addClass('forContaks').html('Контактная информация<img id="downArrow" src="images/arrowDown.png" class="arrowStyle "/>');
     i = !i;
     j = false;
    }
   });
  }
  
 });

Comment: Откройте страницу в хроме, откройте консоль.  
Введите в консоли  

    $( 'selector1' )
На результаты выборки наводите мышкой и смотрите какие блоки попали в выборку, подумайте. каким запросом их исключить.  
Введите запрос  

    $( 'selector1' ).not( selector2 )
Наводите на результаты выборки мышкой и думайте, как их исключить. Повторяйте действия в цикле до достижения желаемого результата.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, буду экспериментировать с запросами, но чесно говоря у меня уже идей нет почти) Возможно Вы подкинуть сможете некоторые?

http://ubuntuone.com/69yW37YTuhHR9nfH9uHYoC - это ссылка на скриншот того что у меня есть, там как раз DOM в консоле выведено, как вы и советовали, однако немогу некак добраться до нужного блока...

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, повесить онклик на body, и проверять, если e.target - нужный нам элемент - то показывать регистрацию, иначе скрывать

Comment: Решил вопрос) совместив 2 совета так сказать) ответ выложил в вопрос) так как комментарии не позволяют весь скрипт запихнуть суда) проблемма была в слойности) при клике на появляющийся div так же был клик и на div что за ним) пришлось через третью переменную фильтровать его)